# Can I use href tag in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to redirect a page in reactjs and for that I want to use href tag can I do that?

Here is the code for reference:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// import DoctorImg from './doctor.jpg';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
<Router>
  <Link to = 'https://google.com/'><button>GO GOOGLE</button></Link>

</Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the Link tag available in React, internally every Link tag is converted to a anchor tag

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


<Link to="/Path" > Contact us </Link>
```

Comment: Using Link from react-router-dom requires the router context, which is way more complicated for a simple link. One can simply use a regular <a href={'http://url'}></a>

Answer (score 9):

If you want to **link to a webpage outside of your React app**, a HTML anchor tag will work great:

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Click here</a>
```

`target="_blank"` will open the webpage in a new tab. `rel="noopener noreferrer"` prevents security risks, more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709625/link-with-target-blank-and-rel-noopener-noreferrer-still-vulnerable)

If you want to **link to a page within your React app** you probably DON'T want to use the  tag because this will cause your whole app to be reloaded, losing the app's current state and causing a delay for the user.

In this case you may want to use a package like [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/) which can move users around your app without reloading it. See Rijul's answer for that solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple href if you want a simple link:

```
<a href={'http://google.com'}>Google</a>
```

Comment: Actually it works very well for me, I don't know why the downvotes. Simpler than having to adopt react router obligatorily.

Comment: @Cristianjs19 Maybe the downvotes are because of the brackets which are not needed if no js variables are required :).  Either way, I agree with you. I think some folks are reading into the questions perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//or if you want to use or own 
//import {yourcomponent} from'your dir'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


<Link to="/Path" exact component={yourCompponent} > Contact us </Link>
```

```html
<!-- if u want to use html -->
<a href ="https://google.com/">clik here </a>
```

Comment: There is an example in the documentation: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link

Answer (score 0):

No, You are not supposed to. href will refresh the current page and open a new one. Technically href will refresh and push one route in history obj. In react i really suggest you to use react-router for routing

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Link to = 'https://google.com/'><button>GO GOOGLE</button></Link>
```

Do like this in react with react router

Comment: Am I required to use switch tag after your suggested code? Because when I press button it's not redirecting me to google website!

Comment: Are you using react router for routing?

Comment: Yes, react-router-dom

Comment: Please check above post I paste code for your reference @sundar

Comment: Think about the question and the provided code - the button they want to make goes to `https://google.com` - so obviously this would refresh the page, and I doubt their website is Google, so react-router-dom is overkill for such a simple thing...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. You can.

```
<Router>
<a href ="https://google.com/"><button>GO GOOGLE</button></a>
</Router>
```

As for "should I" that is another question but for what you have asked the simple answer is yes and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge where i couldn't not simply pass

```
<a className="myClass" href="#">My link</a>
```

I simple changed it to

```
<a className="myClass" href="/#">My link</a>
```

and it worked perfectly well!

Answer (score -3):

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "https://twitter.com/Turkcell" }} 
target="_blank"><i className="icon icon-twitter"/>
</Link>
```

You can use bro.

Comment: <Link to={{ pathname: "https://twitter.com/Turkcell" }} target="_blank" ><i className="icon icon-twitter"/></Link>