# Link with target="_blank" and rel="noopener noreferrer" still vulnerable?

Tags: html

I see people recommending that whenever one uses `target="_blank"` in a link to open it in a different window, they should put `rel="noopener noreferrer"`. I wonder how does this prevent me from using Developer Tools in Chrome, for example, and removing the rel attribute. Then clicking the link...

Is that an easy way to still keep the vulnerability?

Comment: What kind of protection do you think it would (or would not, in this case) grant?

Comment: I was considering browser extensions that can manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Firefox 79 will do this automatically (well, `noopener` at least, but as pointed out below, `noreferrer` is rendundant): https://hacks.mozilla.org/2020/07/firefox-79/

Answer (score 426, accepted):

You may be misunderstanding the vulnerability. You can read more about it here: https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/256-targetblank---the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever/

Essentially, adding `rel="noopener noreferrer"` to links protects your site's users against having the site you've *linked to* potentially hijacking the browser (via rogue JS).

You're asking about removing that attribute via Developer Tools - that would only potentially expose *you* (the person tampering with the attribute) to the vulnerability.

**Update as of 2021:** All current versions of major browsers now  automatically use the behavior of `rel="noopener"` for any `target="_blank"` link, nullifying this issue. See more at [chromestatus.com](https://chromestatus.com/feature/6140064063029248).

Comment: `noopener noreferrer` is redundant, since `noreferrer` includes the functionality of `noopener`. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#link-type-noreferrer

Comment: if its redundant why does Visual Studio Code requires both?

Comment: according to the link in the answer, Firefox does not recognise noopener, so you need to include noreferrer as well

Comment: @AndrewEinhorn Firefox has supported `noopener` for some years now according to caniuse, but IE11 never will. https://caniuse.com/rel-noopener

Comment: [Setting `target="_blank"` on `<a>` elements now implies `rel="noopener"` behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/noopener) for many browsers; See [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#browser_compatibility) for support status.

Comment: Even though all current versions of major browsers changed this behavior, you should still use `rel="noreferrer"` since the user might not be using an up-to-date browser, right?

Comment: @Yulian, correct. We shouldn't assume all users are on the latest browers. This feature has been supported by most browsers since 2021 - An interesting exception is Android Webview. When deciding to include/exclude a feature you should always consider the technology of your own users, not global stats.

Comment: FYI: not exploitable with standard clic, but still exploitable with ctrl+click or mouse scroll wheel button click (sometimes, users use that way to open external links).

Comment: @cactuschibre source?

Comment: @KrzysztofKaczor I do not have source, sorry. I have just tested, you can try! :)

Answer (score 139):

Links with `target="_blank"` on them *[are vulnerable](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/256-targetblank---the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever/)* to having the referrer page being swapped out in the background while the user's attention is diverted by the newly-opened tab. This is known as [**reverse tabnapping**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Reverse_Tabnabbing):

[image: Example malicious flow]

The referring page is stored in [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener), and a malicious site could modify this through:

```
if (window.opener) {
   window.opener.location = "https://phish.example.com";
}
```

Adding `rel="noopener noreferrer"` fixes this vulnerability in all major browsers.

Note that you could theoretically remove the `rel` *client-side* through manipulation... but why would you want to? All you are doing is deliberately making yourself vulnerable to the attack.

Other users who visit the same website (and don't modify their own client-side code) would still be safe, as the server would still serve up the `rel="noopener noreferrer"`. Your removal of it only applies to you.

Comment: just wander, what benefit of rel="noopener noreferrer" gives to my internal application? It opens same internal domain, in same internal network, there is 0 chance that it will be referring to some external site. And if it still would beneficial, why not to add it to all links in general?

Comment: This will stop pages learning about how they are being referred.  Potential this is an unwanted situation, especially when you interested in tracking how users are referred to your site.  I'm not sure if google analytics can get that information if rel="noopener" is set.

Answer (score 51):

### Browsers fix

All major browsers have fixed this issue by updating the default behaviour to be secure without having to specify `rel` property. Read more in [About rel=noopener](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/).

- [Chrome fixed it](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=898942) at v88
- [Safari fixed it](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=155166) in 2016!
- [Firefox fixed it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1222516) at v52
- New Edge is Chromium based, so fixed too

Answer (score 33):

Regarding the [Lighthouse Best Practices audits](https://web.dev/lighthouse-best-practices/) report:

> Add `rel="noopener"` or `rel="noreferrer"` to any external links to
> improve performance and prevent security vulnerabilities.

In general, when you use `target="_blank"`, always add `rel="noopener"` or `rel="noreferrer"`:

For example:

```
<a href="https://www.kaiostech.com/store/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
  KaiStore
</a>
```

- [`rel="noopener"`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#link-type-noopener) prevents the new page from being able to access the `window.opener` property and ensures it runs in a separate process.
- [`rel="noreferrer"`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#link-type-noreferrer) has the same effect but also prevents the `Referer` header from being sent to the new page.

See the [**official document**](https://web.dev/external-anchors-use-rel-noopener/) for more information.

Comment: Can you add both?

Comment: Yes @blessed U can add both like `rel="noopener noreferrer"`

Answer (score 7):

There's no answer pointing out a case when you would actually **want to pass referrer** just ignoring any "security risk" warnings: for instance, when you are linking **your own external website**, which is controlled by you/your org and which presumably has no described security vulnerabilities.

For instance, in my case, in I want to see in Google Analytics how many of my visitors read docs by clicking links inside the web app (which uses a separate domain from where docs are) and how many come from search engines, and hence I want to utilize the referrer header for distinguishing these user groups.

Here's how you can do it when linking websites like your own docs that are safe for sure:

```
{/* Safe link to the own website *//* eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-target-blank */}
<a href="https://my-own-website.com" target="_blank">
  Learn more
</a>
```

In React, I made a wrapper common component to avoid putting `eslint-disable` everywhere in the code (an opposite to `UnsafeExternalLink` component):

```js
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';

/* eslint-disable react/jsx-no-target-blank */

/**
 * Safe link to own external websites only.
 */
const SafeExternalLink = ({
  href,
  children,
}: {
  href: string;
  children: ReactNode;
}) => (
  <a href={href} target="_blank">
    {children}
  </a>
);

export default SafeExternalLink;
```

Comment: You should still add `rel="noopener"` in this scenario, no?

Comment: @Shoelaced I believe rel="noopener" is not necessary either when linking the web pages you own (web pages you trust), but anyway adding it would potentially lower any security risks. In my case, I needed to avoid using just "noreferrer".

Answer (score 4):

The anchor tag `rel=”noopener”` or `rel=”noreferrer”` attributes improve the website security, but some people want to ignore them because they think they will affect their website search engine optimization, but that is just a myth.
It protects the confidentiality of your website audience and prevents external website by spreading malicious code.

Comment: It would be nice if you can cite some source for "myth" statement. Especially, for the `noreferrer` part.

Answer (score 0):

If developer console is showing warning regarding `noopener noreferrer`, make sure you add both `noopener` and `noreferrer` in rel. link should be something like below:

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" />
```

Comment: This does not appear to be addressing the question that was asked.