# Icon which works as a link displayed wrong when the text next to it changes

Tags: html, css

[image: the underscore appears when the text on the left is changed]

[image: this is how it should look]

The second image shows the icon when the page is loaded but when I fires a function that changes the text on the left the icon looks like in the first image, with that little underscore. I have absolutely no idea why. The 'a' tag changes from 60 x 29 to 60.28 x 29 when the text on the left changes, the icon stays 60x60. Any help appreciated.

```
<div class="title" id='title'>This text changes on click and it works fine
 <a href="https://icon.com" target=_blank>
   <img src="icon.svg" id='icon'>
 </a>
</div>
```

```
#icon {
  fill: $mainColor;
  height: 2.5em;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```
function changeText(text) {
document.getElementById('title').firstChild.data = text
/*this is all my JS code, functio fires on button click*/
```

Comment: It is likely the text, not the image, probably coming from `<a href="https://icon.com" target=_blank>`. Make sure to add quotation marks around that `target`! It's a security vulnerability without them. It's also a [**separate** security vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50709760/2341603) to omit the `noopener noreferrer` `rel` attribute...

Comment: If I click the underscore it links to the page, I added quotation marks and rel="noopener noreferrer" but it looks and it works the same as before

Comment: can you add your js code whatever you have tried.

Comment: JS added, but honestly it's very simple and I don't think it's related. Is there a way to fix "a" size to 60x29? the underscore appears when the size changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the first child node’s data somehow makes the browser include the space that was before the link, inside the link now.

If you log the innerHTML to console, you see something like the following:

Before:

```
This text changes on click and it works fine
 <a href="#" target="_blank">
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" id="icon">
 </a>
```

After changing the text:

```
lorem ipsum<a href="#" target="_blank">
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" id="icon">
 </a>
```

(Example output from Chrome.)

So the space is inside the link now, and gets `text-decoration: underline` applied - that is the little line you see on the left of the image.

Funny enough, the effect seems to disappear, if you include a trailing space at the end of the text:

```
document.getElementById('title').firstChild.data = text + " ";
```

---

I can’t give you a full, proper explanation right now of why this happens in the first place - HTML has some rather complex rules how whitespace is treated in DOM creation, specifically at the start or end of an element’s content. Depending on the situation, sometimes such leading or trailing whitespace gets “moved” out of an element, and inserted outside of it, or vice versa.