# Link is not working inside of Div but works outside

Tags: php, html, css

Thanks for taking the time. I trying to make some image links inside of a DIV in html. The links are stored in a SQL DB. The links work just fine when outside of this specific div, but I really want to put them inside for styling purposes. The social images div is the one

```
        echo "<div class=column-3>";


            echo "<h3 id=\"artistNameLabel\"><strong>$artist_name</strong></h3>";
            echo "<img id=\"artistImage\"src=\"imageuploads/$imageFilePath\">";

            echo "<p><a href=\"$artistInstagram\" target=\"_blank\"><img alt=\"Artist Instagram\" src=\"images/instagramLogo.png\" width=\"25%\"></a></p>";//link doesnt work
            echo "<p><a href=\"$artistStreaming\" target=\"_blank\"><img alt=\"Artist Streaming Account\" src=\"images/spotifyLogo.png\" width=\"25%\"></a></p>";//link doesnt work                


        echo "</div>";
```

The images appear just fine, but the link doesn't work. Also the text value that is the link is loaded just fine. Thanks for any help

Comment: What is inside `"$artistInstagram` and `$artistStreaming`? Those are what will be transferred to the links. Also, for what it's worth, you have a [*reverse tabnapping vulnerability*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709625/link-with-target-blank-and-rel-noopener-noreferrer-still-vulnerable/50709760#50709760)

Comment: @ObsidianAge those variables have links to an instagram account and spotify account. They work just fine when put in an HREF outside of this div. And thanks for the tip about tabnapping, i've never heard of that

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<div class=column-3>";
echo "<h3 id='artistNameLabel'><strong>".$artist_name."</strong></h3>";
echo "<img id='artistImage' src='imageuploads/".$imageFilePath."'>";
echo "<p><a href='".$artistInstagram."' target='_blank'><img alt='Artist Instagram' src='images/instagramLogo.png' width='25%'></a></p>";//link doesnt work
echo "<p><a href='".$artistStreaming."' target='_blank'><img alt='Artist Streaming Account' src='images/spotifyLogo.png' width='25%'></a></p>";//link doesnt work                
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this way :

```
$artistInstagram = "https://www.instagram.com/";
$artistStreaming = "https://www.example.com/";
$artist_name = "Test";
$imageFilePath = "https://via.placeholder.com/150";

$html = <<< EOT
<div class=column-3>
    <h3 id="artistNameLabel"><strong>$artist_name</strong></h3>
    <img id="artistImage"src=$imageFilePath>
    <p>
        <a href=$artistInstagram target="_blank">
            <img alt="Artist Instagram" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="5%">
        </a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href=$artistStreaming target="_blank">
            <img alt="Artist Streaming Account" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="5%">
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
EOT;
echo $html;
```

I think this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to style you  anchor tag with "display:inline-block" and it will work fine. no matter if image is there or not.