# Error: Your a element should be nested within your new p element

Tags: html, nested

```
<p>View more 
<a target="_blank" href="http://freecodecamp.org"</a>
cat photos</p>
```

Why does the above code produce this error message on Free Code Camp?

> 'Your a element should be nested within your new p element.'

Comment: You missed the closing `>`.
You're also vulnerable to the [target blank vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709625/link-with-target-blank-and-rel-noopener-noreferrer-still-vulnerable/50709760#50709760), but that's not the source of your error.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are not closing your initial `<a>` tag. i.e.

```
<p>
 View more 
 <a target="_blank" href="http://freecodecamp.org"></a>
 cat photos
</p>
```

Comment: As an aside... The OP *probably* also wants some of the text to be within the `<a>` element.  Though we can't know for certain, as creative styling could also make the link clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i realised the error was the linked web address should have been http://freecatphotoapp.com not http://freecodecamp.org. This was causing it to be rejected.