# Open <a> tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, vuejs2

We have a web application where we load the pdf link from BE and open it using JavaScript like this.

```
 const openLink = () => {
    window.open("http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf", "_blank");
  }
```

This works fine for the web. But we use this same web app in a mobile application as well.
We have a native android and IOS app which provides a web browser and runs the same web app. Users won't feel any difference it will work like a normal mobile app.

But for that mobile app doesn't work above code. A normal `<a>` tag works fine in the mobile app environment as well.

```
<a href='http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf' target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Now our goal is to render a normal  tag and mimic the native onClick event using JavaScript. For some security reason, we cannot directly render the `<a>` tag with the `href` instead we set `href` later using refs. But now we need a way to open the link instead of `window.open()`

This use case may look strange but we have to follow this for some more concerns.
This is my current code

```
function App() {

  const tag = useRef();

  const openLink = () => {
    // window.open("http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf", "_blank");
    tag.current.href = 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf' // set the loaded dynamic pdf link from BE
    // open the link code ...
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <button onClick={openLink}>click me</button>
     <a href='' ref={tag} target="_blank" style={{display:"none"}}></a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: _"For some security reason..."_ - What "security" is this? We're talking about the value of an attribute o.O Anything in the markup is potentially compromised.

Comment: make sure you add `rel="noreferrer"` when using <a> tag to prevents the browser, when navigating to another page, to send this page address, or any other value. This is not necessary in latest browser version. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709625/link-with-target-blank-and-rel-noopener-noreferrer-still-vulnerable/50709760)

Answer (score 0):

In order to work you must be encapsulating the button inside `<a>` **tag**

Using `style={{display: 'none'}}` **won't allow** you to use the `<a>` **tag**

```
  const tag = useRef();

  const openLink = () => {
    // window.open("http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf", "_blank");
    tag.current.href = "http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"; // set the loaded dynamic pdf link from BE
    // open the link code ...
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <a href="" ref={tag} target="_blank">
        <button onClick={openLink}>click me</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
```

**Demo**:
[Demo codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-violet-5ti51?file=/src/App.js)