# How to make a List a hyperlink?

Tags: html, list, web, hyperlink

I'm working on a link list and I can't get the List to be a hyperlink

```
<ul>
 <a href="pdf/VPN.pdf" target="_blank"></a> <li>VPN</li> </a> 
</ul>
```

Comment: The `<li>` goes outside the `<a>`. Also, please remember to add [the appropriate `rel` tags to your hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50709760/2341603).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="pdf/VPN.pdf" target="_blank">VPN</a></li> 
</ul>
```

In your original markup you had the link outside of the list item, and then an extra `</a>` tag at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

`li` stands for "list item". This is the only tag you can have as a direct child of `<ul>...</ul>`, so you have to put your links inside the `<li>`.

Answer (score -1):

you need to put the < li > tag before the entire link code and the < /li > at the end of the entire source tag.

for example =

```html
<ul>
 <li> <a herf = "link you want to post"> Link to stuff </a> </li>
</ul>
```

I hope it helps