# How do I get a button to open an HTML file located on my website?

Tags: php, html, button, hyperlink

It has been a ling time since i have had to code.

My situation is, i need to make a button that open an HTML file that I have located on my website. The HTML file is a interactive course that will open in a new window.

I have tried `<a href="home/file.html" target="_blank"><button>launch Course</button></a>` but I get a "page not found" error.

Comment: Anchors can't have buttons as descendants

Comment: Try this <input type="button" onclick="location.href='YOURPAGE.HTML';" value="NAME BUTTON" />

Comment: @LeoBertass If you are going to use an onclick handler, why switch to an input element? That should work directly on a button element too

Comment: Your best option would probably be to just use an `a` element, and use CSS to make it look like a button

Comment: @grumpyCrouton I have the button looking the exact way I want. I just want it to open and run the html file once it is clicked.

Comment: _"I have the button looking the exact way I want."_ - that is no excuse for not using the _correct_ HTML element for the purpose in the first place. You _want_ link functionality, so you should _use_ a link.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to combine the anchor  tag with  tag. In this case a tag is enough. Also, please check well the path, and verify that the HTML file is in the folder. `<a href="path/to/file.html" target="_blank">/Text</a>`.

To verify that the file is accessible, and the name and the extension is correct, you can copy and paste the path in the browser to see if you can access it. Links can be absolute (the full path from the root, ex: C:/Users/path/to/folder/file.ext) or relative (the short path from the originating folder). If not, re-write the path until it works.

Tip: for security use `rel="noopener noreferrer"` to prevent potential malicious [attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709625/link-with-target-blank-and-rel-noopener-noreferrer-still-vulnerable).

Happy coding Brandon!

Comment: I have made sure that the file path is correct yet i still am receiving a page not found error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your directory with the page you are currently on has the folder home and the html file is located within it.

```
<a href="home/file.html"></a>
```

Here's a example directory

```
/----------
   | index.html(or the current page your on)
   | home -------
           | file.html
```

Comment: I have made sure that the file path is correct, but when it opens it just give me a page not found error.

Comment: is the file public. is it being served?